# next js localhost:3000 refused to connect after npm audit fix force

Tags: next.js, localhost

when I npm start to run Hello World, my localhost is still working. After that, I install ant design and redux toolkit with npm install antd and npm install @reduxjs/toolkit. Then I use npm audit fix force to fix severity vulnerability. And now, my localhost is confuse to connect.

I try turn off firewall on window, clear cookies but it still not working.